# How can I move the first tab above?

Tags: html, css

I want to rise above #first_tab so as to be in line with all the others.
I have done wrong in this code?

This is the site:

http://dl.dg-site.com/presentations/

Can you help me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Code CSS:

```
     #first_tab
{
        width:210px;height:540px;
        display:inline-block;
        background: #264572;
}

#content_first{font-size: 14px;color:white;font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding-left: 10px;}

#title_first{text-align:left;color:#8CC63F; font-family: muli, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    line-height: 1.4;padding-left: 10px;}


#second_tab
{
        width:210px;height:540px;
        display:inline-block;
        background: #264572;
        margin-left: 10px;

}

 #third_tab
{
        width:210px;height:540px;
        display:inline-block;
        background: #264572;
        margin-left:10px;
}


#four_tab
{
        width:210px;height:540px;
        display:inline-block;
        background: #264572;
        margin-left: 10px;

}
```

Code HTML:

```
 <div id="first_tab">
   <p id="title_first">Qualité</p>
   <p id="content_first">Le souci de qualité de nos installations, de standards européens, est au coeur de notre activité. C’est pourquoi nous choisissons des partenaires de qualité et de savoir-faire, tels que Philips, Bosch, Zanussi.</p>


</div>

<div id="second_tab">



</div>

<div id="third_tab">



</div>

<div id="four_tab">



</div>
```

Comment: I found the problem to be the content (the <p>'s) inside the first_tab div. if you remove them, the column's height is restored. Now I need to see what is wrong with the p's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `display:inline-block` the default alignment is `baseline`

You have to set this to `vertical-align:top`

```css
     #first_tab {
         width:210px;
         height:540px;
         display:inline-block;
         background: #264572;
         vertical-align: top;
     }
     #content_first {
         font-size: 14px;
         color:white;
         font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
         padding-left: 10px;
     }
     #title_first {
         text-align:left;
         color:#8CC63F;
         font-family: muli, sans-serif;
         font-size: 24px;
         font-weight: 500;
         letter-spacing: 2px;
         line-height: 1.4;
         padding-left: 10px;
     }
     #second_tab {
         width:210px;
         height:540px;
         display:inline-block;
         background: #264572;
         margin-left: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
     }
     #third_tab {
         width:210px;
         height:540px;
         display:inline-block;
         background: #264572;
         margin-left:10px;
    vertical-align: top;
     }
     #four_tab {
         width:210px;
         height:540px;
         display:inline-block;
         background: #264572;
         margin-left: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
     }
```

```html
<div id="first_tab">
    <p id="title_first">Qualité</p>
    <p id="content_first">Le souci de qualité de nos installations, de standards européens, est au coeur de notre activité. C’est pourquoi nous choisissons des partenaires de qualité et de savoir-faire, tels que Philips, Bosch, Zanussi.</p>
</div>
<div id="second_tab"></div>
<div id="third_tab"></div>
<div id="four_tab"></div>
```

By the way...you have a **lot** of repeated CSS in your code. You should really try streamlining that into classes that can be individually applied to each element. See [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5kbjr641/1/)

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
float: left;
```

to #first_tab

Comment: did you see if this fixes the problem?

Comment: It will fix the problem in this particular case, but it defiles the logic behind display: inline-block and you will get problems if you add more columns. Paulie_Ds solution a bit further up seems to be the best answer to this.

Comment: sorry, indeed it does fix for this problem, at first it did not do it here, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Add float:left for all tab class
 #first_tab
{
        width:210px;height:540px;
        display:inline-block;
        background: #264572;
        float: left;
}
#second_tab
{
        width:210px;height:540px;
        display:inline-block;
        background: #264572;
        margin-left: 10px;
        float: left;

}

 #third_tab
{
        width:210px;height:540px;
        display:inline-block;
        background: #264572;
        margin-left:10px;
        float: left;
}


#four_tab
{
        width:210px;height:540px;
        display:inline-block;
        background: #264572;
        margin-left: 10px;
        float: left;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

add in the #first_tab"

`margin: 0 auto;
position: absolute;`